# The array A [N] contains natural numbers. Find the sum of those elements that are multiples of a given K

Tags: javascript

I would appreciate if you could help me find an error in my code. Sorry, I'm new as you can see.

```js
var arr = prompt("Enter your numbers separating by comma").split(",");
arr = arr.map(Number);
var n = prompt("N");
let arr1;
var n = parseInt(n);
for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr.get(i) % n == 0) {
    function() {
      arr1 = arr.get(i);
    }
  }
}
console.log(arr1);
```

Comment: You're never calling the function you define in the loop.

Comment: `arr1 = arr.get(i);` is wrapped in an anonymous function, but why? This is what causes the error. In addition you'll want to use `let arr1 = 0;` and `arr1 += arr[i];` (and access element i using `arr[i]` elsewhere, too, also consider naming it `sum` instead of `arr1`)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to create internal function within for loop:

```
let sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] % n === 0) {
      sum += arr[i];
  }
}
```

Or more JS-way:

```
const sum = arr.filter(e => e % n === 0).reduce((a, c) => a + c);
```

Answer (score 2):

The function is not needed. You should just add the array element to a total variable.

Array elements are accessed as `arr[i]`, not `arr.get(i)`.

```js
var arr = prompt("Enter your numbers separating by comma").split(",");
arr = arr.map(Number);
var n = prompt("N");
let total = 0;
var n = parseInt(n);
for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] % n == 0) {
    total += arr[i];
  }
}
console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 1):

that?

```js
var arr = (prompt("Enter your numbers separating by comma").split(",")).map(Number)
  , n = parseInt( prompt("N") )
  ;
console.log( arr.reduce((r,v)=>r+(v%n?0:v),0) )
```